# Weather Forecast. Сохранить температуру в указанное время

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

WebAPI, стандартный шаблон Weather Forecast. Нужно создать post запрос, который сохранит температуру в указанное время. Я буквально сегодня начал WebAPI учить, и совсем не понимаю как это сделать.
Я себе это представляю как List, созданный в отдельном классе, чтобы данные не пропали после завершения запроса. И добавить HttpPost контроллер с методом, который бы добавлял в созданный List температуру в указанное время. Получается время использовалось бы как id.

Но мне кажется что это не так должно работать, потому что куча вопросов появляется. Какой тип указывать для List? Что, если нужно будет так же по указанному времени удалить температуру из List? Это же не получится, ведь в листе только значения температуры. И как именно, где указать время?

По этому подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно решить эту задачу - сохранить температуру в указанное время.

Comment: В базу данных писать надо.

Comment: поддерживаю aepot'а, писать в базу данных в таблицу типа `Id (int autoincrement) | Temperature (Double) | Time (DateTime)`